# How do I stop the flutter video player from playing my old video?

Tags: dart, flutter

When I am using my app, I have a ListView.builder, and if someone presses an item on that it does a Navigator.push function and leads them to the corresponding video. However, if I pause the video in the middle, when Navigator.pop is called, it pops the window, but if I play another video after that, it resumes the old video and then starts the new video. Can anyone help me on how to stop the issue?

Comment: Can you post some code please?